# system.err Error: Could not find or load main class org.sonar.runner.Main

Tags: gradle, sonar-runner

trying to upgrade sonar-runner from 2.4 to 2.5, using gradle version 2.3

here is the snippet from build.gradle:

```
classpath 'org.codehaus.sonar.runner:sonar-runner-dist:2.5'
```

and i use the following to upload the `sonar-runner-dist-2.5.jar`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar.runner</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-runner-dist</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

to nexus

but get error when running

`gradle build :noINT :Backend:TestServices:sonarRunner`

error:

```
[system.err] Error: Could not find or load main class org.sonar.runner.Main
```

also, i have sonar-runner 2.4 working, with the following configuration:

Group: org.codehaus.sonar.runner
Artifact: sonar-runner-dist
Version: 2.4 
Extension: jar
XML:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar.runner</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-runner-dist</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a summary:

I am trying to use SonarQube version 5.3 , with sonar-runner version 2.5

First i run sonar-runner 2.4 against sonarQube 5.2 which works fine , but when i upgrade sonar-runner via local nexus repo to sonar-runner 2.5 and run it against sonarQube 5.3

i get build failed and the exception:

```
16:31:05.880 [ERROR] [system.err] Error: Could not find or load main class org.sonar.runner.Main
16:31:05.887 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
16:31:05.887 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java'' finished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)
16:31:05.887 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':Backend:E2Services:sonarRunner'
16:31:05.887 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :Backend:E2Services:sonarRunner FAILED
16:31:05.888 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :Backend:E2Services:sonarRunner (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.544 secs.
16:31:05.888 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 3,5,main]] finished, busy: 10 mins 55.24 secs, idle: 0.025 secs
16:31:05.888 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:31:05.889 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:31:05.889 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:31:05.889 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:31:05.889 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':Backend:E2Services:sonarRunner'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Sonar Scanner 1.2 , problem fixed.